Why am I getting too many authentication failures yet didn't asked for password with SSH on macOS?
When attempting to ssh to any host using the following command :
ssh 192.168.1.5

I get the following error :
Received disconnect from 192.168.1.5 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from 192.168.1.5 port 22

Now, I used another argument to the command -vvvv and I figured out that the SSH program is trying all the SSH keys and fails because none of them actually match my host (192.168.1.5) which is correct.
But yet, I do not remember disabling password authentication. I searched inside the configs file, but didn't find any config line that explicit force authentication through ssh key.
How can I re-enable username / password authentication along SSH key authentication ? Or yet a more brutal workaround - how may I reset completely my SSH configuration without loosing my keys ?

Without the OpenSSH configuration file there is no way to help you. If passes authentication is disabled you will have to enable it by editing the configuration file. You should be able to stop and then start the service in verbose mode to determine where the configuration file is.

I figured it out:
I have multiple SSH keys setup which aren't linked to specific domains or IPs. Therefore, all of them were being tested and all of them failed (which is how it is supposed to work). Once all the keys failed, the next authentication method is username and password.
However, I would never reach that part because the server I was trying to connect to had a limitation in the number of allowed login attempts.
So, it wasn't that I was missing the settings but rather that I haven't restricted my keys to specific hosts.
